# Number of cluster similarities

Tags: clustering

As I know, for a fixed set of $ N $ documents there are up to $ N^2 $ distinct similarities between clusters in single-link and complete-link clustering. In which way can I define how many distinct cluster similarities there are in GAAC and centroid clustering?